# Regex in php to match this pageName parameter

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am creating a script in PHP to scrape the pageName string out of my html source code. My script needs to pull out the string between the speech marks.

```
s.pageName        = "Garden: Sheds & Storage: Wooden Sheds";
```

Something like this:

```
if (preg_match("/s.pageName = \"(.*?)\"/", $html, $matches)) {

    var_dump($matches);


}
```

Can you help me form a working regex for this.

Comment: What's wrong with your attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `\s+` or `\s*` to skip multiple white spaces. Here is an example:

```
$text = <<<EOT
s.pageName        = "Garden: Sheds & Storage: Wooden Sheds";
EOT;

if (preg_match('/s\.pageName\s+=\s+"(.*?)";/', $text, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=pageName\s=\s").+(?=";)
```

That should work

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Dhx8MI0jHOZv8Whb)